# How to fix this syntax error, please help me

Tags: syntax, php

when i run file its appear with error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/beddings/public_html/mybabystore.com.au/admin/categories.php on line 2364

here is my code

```
$contents[] = array(
    'align' => 'center', 
    'text' => '<br><a href="' . 
        tep_href_link(
            FILENAME_CATEGORIES, 
            '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID.'&checkall=1') 
        . '" onClick="setCheckboxes('mainForm', true); return false;">[Check All Products]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' 
        . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID) 
        . '" onClick="setCheckboxes('mainForm', true); return false;">[Un Check All]</a>'
);
```

Comment: This looks okay there should be some other problem. Paste full code. Lets have look

Comment: Why does your php code contain this `$contents[] = array('align' => 'center', 'text' => '
[Check All Products]  [Un Check All]');` ? I mean why is the second value for the key **text** is enclosed with square braces ?

Comment: @dreamweiver that was an issue with the op pasting code and not formatting it properly

Answer (score 2):

The error is here, you need to escape your single quotes

```
setCheckboxes(\'mainForm\', true); 
              ^----------^
//You are using this twice so escape the other one too
```

Comment: Shouldnt **"** (doubled quotes) escape **'** (Single quotes ) as well ?

Comment: @dreamweiver That's an alternative :)

Comment: Then i suppose, there was no need for the single quotes to be escaped,since its already enclosed with double quotes in the question

Comment: @dreamweiver Test it yourself on local\

Answer (score 0):

Try this You need to escape the single quotes

```
$contents[] = array('align' => 'center', 'text' => '<br><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID.'&checkall=1') . '" onClick="setCheckboxes(\'mainForm\', true); return false;">[Check All Products]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID) . '" onClick="setCheckboxes(\'mainForm\', true); return false;">[Un Check All]</a>');
```

Comment: @chandresh_cool Don't ask for upvotes, you'll get them if people want to

Comment: agreed @AcidicCloud cloud hence deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$contents[] = array('align' => 'center', 'text' => '<br><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID.'&checkall=1') . '" onClick="setCheckboxes(\'mainForm\', true); return false;">[Check All Products]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, '&cPath='. $cPath.'&cID='.$cID) . '" onClick="setCheckboxes(\'mainForm\', true); return false;">[Un Check All]</a>');
```